# redirect to another page after logging in

Tags: php

I am working on how to redirect to another page by suing header() function, but it's not working, and give me an error message saying hat:Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by......  Anyone could help, thanks a lot.
here is my php code

```
 if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
     $query = "select email, password from member where email = '$email' and   password='$pass'";
     if(mysql_num_rows(queryMysql($query)) == 0)
{
   echo "Email/Password invalid<br/>";
}
else
{
    $query1 ="select uniid from member where email = '$email' and password ='$pass'";
     $result1 = queryMysql($query1);
      $row1 = mysql_fetch_object($result1);
      $uniid = $row1->uniid; 
       $_SESSION['uniid'] = $uniid;

       header("Location:View.php?view=$uniid");
   }
     }
```

Comment: There are probably like 1 million cases of this issue plastered all over online...

Comment: @tony: Wow!? Wait a minute. I sure hope that's not real code... You have a major security flaw there. Always sanitize the user input before querying the database! `mysql_real_escape_string()`, `mysqli_real_escape_string()` or even better use `PDO` and prepared statements. Or does `queryMysql()` handle that?

Comment: Robert'); DROP TABLE STUDENTS http://xkcd.com/327/  Though that's not a valid MySQL exploit :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider starting your code with `ob_start()`. This turns off output buffering, which in short allows you to use `header()` and `setcookie()` anywhere at all.

Comment: The cookie issue is always a gotcha.  It's easy to forget that is output for the http packet.

Answer (score 3):

THe headers must be sent *before* you write anything else. Put the header re-direct at the top of your code and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have any output (not even whitespace), before your call to header().

You can hunt down any opportunity for output, or you can start output buffering on the first line of your script.  That will cause output to be buffered until either the end of the script, or an explicit call to ob_flush() (or similar functions). See [ob_start()](http://php.net/ob_start)

Answer (score 0):

A header must precede any output from the program.  So, if you echo *anything* before the header modification, you will get that error.  If you don't want to rearrange your code, you can use output buffering to delay other output until the header is sent.

See:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause for this problem is that something somewhere is printing something to stdout before you send your header.  You can either use ob_start as Kolink said, or you can turn on a global output buffer in php.ini, which will allow PHP to automagically send the header output first.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there is no whitespace in your PHP file at all, in particular before the opening PHP tag. This counts as text output and it can't occur before sending headers.